# The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'NoName'

Tags: c#, sql, jet, dbase

The `INSERT INTO` statement contains the following unknown field name:

> '`NoName`'.  Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the
>   operation again.

That is the error thrown when I try to insert a record into a `dbase` file (`.dbf`) from a `.Net` app I am working on.

I use `Oledb` connection like this:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\David\Desktop\Dbase_Files;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=");
```

I had similar issues while selecting. Some columns get returned as '`NoName`' but still with data. I simply use the column index number in place of the column name.

Now I need to insert and it has been a block. Same error comes up with say (when you don't list out the column names):

```
INSERT INTO [tablename.dbf] VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

Sample full code below:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\David\Desktop\Dbase_Files;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=");

connection.Open();

OleDbTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO [tablename.DBF] 
                                        VALUES
                                        (
                                        ?, ?, ?
                                        );", connection, trans);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", 7);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", "RCN");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param3", 0);

try
{
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    trans.Commit();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    trans.Rollback();
    throw e;
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

I have seen forums discuss this when it happens in `Ms Access`. But nothing much so far on `dbase`. Been thinking it is a `driver` thing.

The `dbase` file was created by `dbase plus (2007)` application.

Comment: Does the table you're updating have 3 fields (in the order that you're supplying the values)?

Comment: Yes it does. I just noticed that the 'NoName' comes when the field name is longer than 8 or 9 characters. I am not allowed to change the fieldname. There might be some tweek via the connection string. dbase is a pain.

Comment: dBase is usually `DBF` and SQL Server is usually `MDF`. Are you certain this is an MDF file? Anyway, this link implies that for long field names you need a 'dictionary' file - do you have those? Even if you do, they may have been automatically created with in correct info. http://www.alphasoftware.com/alphaforum/showthread.php?30532-DBASE-10-Character-Limit-Field-Names

Comment: Apologies. DBF actually.

Comment: Try to remove square brackets, as well as .DBF extension from the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out after a long time that this happened to tables with field-name longer than 8 or 9 characters. When its 10 or more  characters long, the field name returns 'NoName'.
It sounds ridiculous. 
When I made the field-name shorter this worked fine.

I got some insight into this [here](http://www.alphasoftware.com/alphaforum/showthread.php?30532-DBASE-10-Character-Limit-Field-Names)

Now with the fieldnames adjusted, my sample code above works perfectly.

Comment: This is horrible! that's not a MS bug its a GIANT INSECT!!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use question marks in combination with named parameters, even `@param1` etc. If you're inserting three values into this table, then name the parameters in the command text:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\David\Desktop\Dbase_Files;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;User ID=Admin;Password=");

connection.Open();

OleDbTransaction trans = connection.BeginTransaction();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"INSERT INTO [tablename.DBF] 
                                        VALUES
                                        (
                                        @param1, @param2, @param3
                                        );", connection, trans);

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", 7);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", "RCN");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param3", 0);

try
{
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    trans.Commit();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    trans.Rollback();
    throw e;
}
finally
{
    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: [`OleDbCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not support named parameters for text commands.  `?` must be used.

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, but what you are probably failing on is the telling of WHICH columns you are inserting the values.  Yes, OleDB uses "?" as place-holders for the parameters and they must match the same order as their corresponding needs of the SQL select, insert, update or delete.  Add the explicit columns BEFORE the "Values" clause.

```
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(
   @"INSERT INTO [tablename.DBF] ( tblColumn1, tblColumn2, tblColumn3 )
        VALUES  ( ?, ?, ? )", connection, trans);

THEN add your parameters in the specific order to match the command.
```

No need for the closing semi within the command statement as you only had one insert command anyhow.

The actual naming of the parameters as you had was ok for your own clarification, but the order of parameters is specifically correlated to the "?" place-holders in the insert statement.